# Get in new file output from command inside bash script

Tags: bash

this is part of my code:

```
for i in $(ls  $1); do
    input_file1=$i
    NOEXT1=${base1%.*}
    for j in $( ls $2); do
        input_file2=$j
        base2=${j##*/}
        NOEXT2=${base2%.*}
        intersectBed  -u -a $1$input_file1 -b $2$input_file2 | wc | awk '{print $1}'
        #echo $NOEXT1"_VS_"$NOEXT2
        wc $1$input_file1 | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'
        wc $2$input_file2 | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'
    done
done
```

`$1` and `$2` are folders I define.

What I want to do is for every loop to create a new file that will be written with the output of the `intersectBed  -u -a $1$input_file1 -b $2$input_file2` without braking the loop and without interapting the output of the `wc $1$input_file1 | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'`and `wc $2$input_file2 | awk '{print $1"\t"$4}'`, outputs

Comment: I think you mean `for i in "$1"/*`.  [Don't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: I need the full path
the $i will only give me filename

Comment: Also, I could not find a better way to get files and filenames and add them as a "counter" to perform a for routine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but just redirect the output to the file you want.  It doesn't affect the rest of the script at all.

```
intersectBed  -u -a "$1$input_file1" -b "$2$input_file2" | wc -l >outputfile
```

(The `awk` script seems superfluous here; `wc` has an option to only print the line count.  Notice also the additional quoting.)

With some refactoring to fix obvious warts, try this:

```
for i in "$1"/*; do
    input_file1=$i
    NOEXT1=${base1%.*}
    for j in "$2"/*; do
        input_file2=$j
        base2=${j##*/}
        NOEXT2=${base2%.*}

        intersectBed  -u -a "$i" -b "$j" | wc -l >insect_$NOEXT1_$NOEXT2

        #echo $NOEXT1"_VS_"$NOEXT2

        wc -l "$i" "$j"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
...but, I have to ask what the quotation does?
and in the intersectBed command the "$j2" is a mistake?
the command as is cannot read from a file so that is why I have to specify the exact file in easch $1 or $2 folder

Comment: Probably, I have to  rephrase the question. I only need the 'intersectBed -u -a $1$input_file1 -b $2$input_file2' to be exported to new separate files. not the rest pipeline

Comment: Yeah, the `"$j2"` was a mistake; thanks for spotting that. I have fixed it now. The quoting is required in order to correctly cope with file names containing spaces etc; this is (massively) a FAQ so I won't explain in more detail here.

Comment: As far as I can understand your question and your attenpts to rephrase it, this answers your question and solves your problem. Is there something I still need to explain?

Comment: I did it like that:
`for i in "$1"/*; do
    input_file1=$i
    NOEXT1=${base1%.*}
    for j in "$2"/*; do
        input_file2=$j
        base2=${j##*/}
        NOEXT2=${base2%.*}

        intersectBed  -u -a "$i" -b "$j"  >insect_$NOEXT1_$NOEXT2
        wc -l insect_$NOEXT1_$NOEXT2
        #echo $NOEXT1"_VS_"$NOEXT2

        wc -l "$i" "$j"
    done
done`